# What "both ways" is Narrator referring to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Fight Club (1999)*, Narrator looks down the barrel of a gun that's been stuck in his mouth.
The gun is held by a man named Tyler:

> Narrator: For a second, I forget about Tyler's controlled demolition
> thing and I wonder how clean that gun is.
>
> Tyler: It's getting exciting now.
>
> Narrator: That old saying, how you always hurt the one you love, well,
> it works **both ways**.

What "both ways" is Narrator referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two readings I can see:

- You always hurt the ones you love and the ones you love always hurt you
- You always hurt the ones you love and love the ones you hurt

It's hard to tell from the context posted which is meant, but I suspect from my hazy memory of the novel that the second is more likely.